# Delete a file without safenet discover it?

Tags: hacker-experience

I don't know if it's a bug but we have missions that we need to delete files to be paid. Each time I delete a file, at the exact time the file is deleted, I get a mail from safenet telling me that I'm tracked.

I don't even have time to delete my logs. Because of that, delete software mission are impossible to do. Am I missing something?

Note: My firewall is like v22.4 so I don't think it's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's random, whenever you do something illegal, such as deleting files, ddosing, or transferring money, you have a random percent chance to land on the Safenet warning list, it has nothing to do with clearing your logs, but if you wait, you'll be taken off of it, but you can also change your IP using the Internet Service Provider (ISP).

I suggest not doing anything majorly illegal until you get off of the Safenet warning list, as it could place you on the FBI list where people can get a bounty for ddosing you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the logs after you hacked into the server?

There will be a record of your login, so that might be triggering the safenet alert when a file is deleted.

Comment: He says that: hack in -> delete logs -> delete software -> delete logs

Comment: Yup I delete my logs for each action I make so yeah I've deleted my logon log before starting to delete the software.

Comment: Are you using SSH exploit to delete the file? is it higher Version than the server firewall?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're deleting too many files within a time frame. If you delete a certain amount in an hour, day, or week, the safe net will track you. You are probably over your limit. I recommend deleting logs As soon as you delete any file.